# GMAIL REST API using service account - Empty or missing scope not allowed

Tags: php, google-oauth, gmail-api, service-accounts

I a trying to get the latest emails from my `GMAIL` inbox via the *GMAIL REST API v2* and using a [service account key (a solution for server to server communication)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts). However, I get the following error:

```
{ "error": "invalid_scope", "error_description": "Empty or missing scope not allowed." }
```

Below is my PHP code. I have used composer to install the [google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Has anyone encountered and solved this issue?

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('serviceaccount-xxxxxxxxx.json');

try{
  $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
  $opt_param['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
  $opt_param['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
  $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$opt_param);
  $list = $messages->getMessages();
  var_dump($list);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: [Tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661489/gmail-api-insufficient-permission)?

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I forgot to set the scope $client->setScopes($scopes); However, now I get a "failedprecondition" error because I haven't impersonate the service. From the below discussion, it seems impersonation only works with a Google domain or Google Apps, which is not the case for me since I am using my personal Google Account. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341096/gmail-rest-api-using-google-credentials-without-impersonate)