# Google Application Default Credentials - "Insufficient Permission" in development & "Bad Request" in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-client

I'm using [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) to fetch the list of Labels using Gmail API.

While running the application locally using `gcloud preview app run` command, I'm getting `HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user%40domain.com/labels?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">`

Then I deployed the application and tried to access. But I got `HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user%40domain.com/labels?alt=json returned "Bad Request">`

I have correct configuration in `gcloud config list`:

```
account = my_email@domain.com (Appengine Application Owener & Domain Admin)
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = <appengine_project_id>
```

gcloud version details:

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.76
app 2015.08.27
app-engine-python 1.9.25
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2015.08.27
core-nix 2015.06.02
gcloud 2015.08.27
gsutil 4.14
gsutil-nix 4.12
preview 2015.08.27
```

Also I have added the service account's Client ID & Gmail Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly in Google Apps admin CPanel and Gmail API enabled in Appengine Console.

Here is the Code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

class Connection:
    def __init__(cls):
        cls.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

    def fetch_labels(cls):
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=cls.credentials)

        logging.info(service)

        results = service.users().labels().list(userId='user@domain.com').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            logging.info('No labels found.')
        else:
            logging.info('Labels:')
            for label in labels:
                logging.info(label['name'])
        pass


class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        con = Connection()
        con.fetch_labels()
```

Comment: Create a service account and download the JSON key. Put it in /home/{username}/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json. Then try again from the devserver after restarting it. I think the deployed application error is different.

Comment: @ernestoalejo I will try that. If it works, It will only fix this issue in local environment. Production application will have the error :(

Comment: Yes, it's only to fix the devserver. In production is it possible that Google Apps is not correctly configured like this answer says? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29328258/478440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% certain on this, but I do not think that Application Default Credentials supports domain-wide delegation of authority. You will still need to use Service Account Credentials with the `sub` argument:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    service_account_email, service_account_key,
    scope='...', sub=user_email)
```

Comment: You are right. ACD won't support domain wide delegation.