# Send email through Gmail API Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

Trying to send email using the `Gmail API` into `GAE`. Previously I created a Service account key into Credentials page, it generates a `.P12 file` which is in `setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File` parameter. It has a ID key joined to the account `example@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` into Service account page. The code:

```
    /* Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "appnamefromappengine";

    String emailAddress = "somename@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
        scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND);
        scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE);
        scopes.add(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/home/myuser/Test/src/main/webapp/resources/**somename**cd30e7118ad5.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountUser("somename@appspot.gserviceaccount.com")
            .build();
        Gmail gmail = new Gmail
            .Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("someemail@gmail.com"));
        message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("recipient@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Test Mail");
        message.setText("Test Mail");

        Message msg = createMessageWithEmail(message); //createMessageWithEmail function from Gmail API
        msg = gmail.users().messages().send(emailAddress, msg).execute();

        System.out.println("Mail was sent. Message id: " + msg.getId());

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It returns me this error:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
>   Bad Request
>   {   "code" : 400,
>   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Bad Request",
>       "reason" : "failedPrecondition"   } ],
>   "message" : "Bad Request" }

I'm not sure which parameter I'm setting wrong here in code or into Google cloud console. What else can I try ?

Comment: Check this SO question [Gmail REST API : 400 Bad Request + Failed Precondition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition) if it can help you :)

Comment: Was the link provided by @KENdi helpful?  Have you been able to narrow down or address the failing precondition?

Comment: It was @Nicholas. The problem was that I didn't configure Delegate domain-wide authority to the service account into admin console. Either way all the code is completely working if someone wants to send an email using Gmail API. The question could be complemented answer how to use Email API authorized senders into the code. Once someone registered an email in that section, how to reference that email. Thanks for all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the issue.  Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't configure Delegate domain-wide authority to the service account into Admin console.

> 1. Go to your Google Apps domain’s Admin console.
> 2. Select Security from the list of controls. If you don't see Security
>      listed, select More controls from the gray bar at the
>          bottom of the page, then select Security from the list of controls.
>          If you can't see the controls, make sure you're signed in as an
>          administrator for the domain.
> 3. Select Show more and then Advanced settings from the list of
>      options.
> 4. Select Manage API client access in the Authentication section.
> 5. In the Client Name field enter the service account's Client ID. You
>      can find your service account's client ID
>          in the
>              Service
>                      accounts section of the Developers Console's Permissions page.
> 6. In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that
>      your application should be granted access to.
>          For
>                  example, if
>                          your application needs domain-wide access to the Google Drive API
>                          and the Google Calendar API, enter:
>                          https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,
>                          https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.
> 7. Click Authorize.

All the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: the problem with this is that it gives the service account access to all accounts in such domain within the specified scope, which might not be ideal. Google doesn't provide a way to only limit it to a single or a number of specific accounts within that domain. Also, it is only available to G Suite customers. Normal Gmail accounts don't have this.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you could use a library like this one, who will do all of the set up for you:
https://github.com/3wks/spring-gae-gmail