# Send through gmail service account showing error

Tags: c#, authentication, gmail-api, service-accounts

When I am sending mail through gmail service account using gmailapi it is showing the following error.

**Errors [
Message[Precondition check failed.] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] Domain[global]
]**
My Gmail service account is a free gmail account. Authentication with service account is working but send mail is not working and showing above error.
Please suggest me how to resolve the issue.
Here is code i am using to send mail

'''

```
 MimeMessage email = createEmail(to, from, subject, body);// calling the createEmail Function to create the mail message
                Message message = new Message();
                message.Raw = StringToBase64url(email.ToString());
                var sa1 = service.Users.Messages.Send(message, userId).Execute();
                return sa1;'''
```

Comment: try this seems like a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition

Comment: Service accounts cannot send emails. They can impersonate regular accounts and send emails on behalf of them, but they cannot send them by themselves. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328258 for how to impersonate another account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail REST API : 400 Bad Request + Failed Precondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition)

Answer (score 1):

try to activated option allow less secure app access in your google account